# Environment Variable not being passed to CruiseControl, specifically the 'nodosfilewarnings' ENV variable from Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, windows-server-2008, cruisecontrol.net

I have a Perl program that someone else created and I am calling on with CruiseControl.  The program calls on Unix Commands using Cygwin.  However, everytime that the Perl program calls on a Unix like command with a DOS like address, I get the well known error:

```
cygwin warning:
   MS-DOS style path detected: E:\regression
   Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/e/regression
   CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
     http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
```

I have set both the User Variable AND System Variable `CYGWIN` to `nodosfilewarning`. This removes the error when I run the program from the command line, but the error still occurs in CruiseControl when called as an automated process from a batch file.  I have called on both the batch file from the Desktop AND Command Line and ran as an administrator.  Nothing changes.

Other Notes

- For purposes of this problem, I don't have access to the Perl Program
- I am trying to go back to Cygwin 1.5.*, but since I am using Server 2008, I am encountering compatibility issues
- This is occurring on one of the distributed servers, not the main server running the Webdashboard.
- I have read somewhere that this issue may stem from a different user calling on CruiseControl, but the issue ***should*** have been solved by setting this as an ENV System variable
- Is it possible to modify the registery to set the ENV variables?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "...error still occurs in CruiseControl when called... from a batch file": can you set the variable explicitly in the batch file?

Comment: Did that.  I set the ENV variable from the batch script before CruiseControl was called and at the beginning of the script (which I was able to get a hold of).  Apparently CYGWIN wants to look directly at the system variables...?  At least that is what many forums have said that I found

Comment: On my machine, I have a variable called `%HOME%` that points to a directory for cygwin to use as my user home directory.  Within that directory is a file named `.bash_profile` in which I set the cygwin environment variables as such: `export the_variable=thevalue`.  You might try to find your `.bash_profile` and `export` like that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is like this

```bsh
printf 'export CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Tried that, but it seems that Cygwin/Windows ignores bashrc files in some cases (this being one of them).  The one that I see time and time again is adding it to the ENV System Variables

Answer (score 0):

If CruiseControl is connecting to the server via ssh, reinstall `sshd` and explicitly include `nodosfilewarning` when prompted for the `CYGWIN` environment variable during the install.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing with modified environment will work but if you don't want to or cannot re-install, an alternative is to change the registry instead of re-installing the service.

See: [CYGWIN windows cygrunsrv sshd server and MS-DOS style path detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201490/cygwin-windows-cygrunsrv-sshd-server-and-ms-dos-style-path-detected)