# CYGWIN windows cygrunsrv sshd server and MS-DOS style path detected

Tags: windows, cygwin, warnings, dos, sshd

The idea is to get rid of the CYGWIN warning given when one connects to the cygwin deamon running as a service in the windows box (sshd):

Problematic case:

```
> ssh -i <my private key> me@server "ls d://path//to//folder//"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: d://path//to//folder//
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/path/to/folder/
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
  http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
[...]
```

This warning can cause a remote command executed to return a warning instead of '0' status code.

The warning tells us to set the following value in the CYGWIN environment variable: *"nodosfilewarning"*

The problem is that wether one sets it in any the following places, it does not get into the remote environment:

- Windows user environment variables
- Windows System environment variables
- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.profile
- /etc/bashrc
- /etc/profile
  etc.

Test case:

```
> ssh -i <my private key> me@server "env | grep CYGWIN"
CYGWIN=CYGWIN sshd
```

The CYGWIN environment variable never contains the proper value regardless of where you set it...

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the fact that *sshd* is run with *cygrunsrv.exe* which is set up from calling in the CYGWIN terminal *ssh-host-config*. It sets at install time a default value for the CYGWIN environment variable if not modified with the *-c* flag... 
or if it is not modified when Queried from the *ssh-host-config* script execution:

```
*** Query: Enter the value of CYGWIN for the deamon: [] CYGWIN sshd
```

See the *./bin.ssh-host-config* script for the options and details.

```
 --cygwin -c <options>  Use \"options\" as value for CYGWIN environment var
```

Modifying the CYGWIN environment variable without un-installing the service and re-doing the installation with the *-c* flag is not possible as far as I know! 
Modifying the parameters of the service once installed is however possible if you edit the registry value found here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sshd\Parameters\Environment CYGWIN
```

Modifying the entry and appending *nodosfilewarning* at the end of the value will fix our problem!

We can verify that it has indeed worked by re-executing the test case again:

```
> ssh -i <my private key> me@server "env | grep CYGWIN"
CYGWIN=CYGWIN sshd nodosfilewarning
```

From then on, executing the problematic case should not display the warning message anymore!